# Is is possible to access graph from an ip address when training on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-ec2, ip-address, yolo

I am training the YOLOv4 network with the [darknet repo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects). There is a way to track the mAP of one's validation set through opening a port with an IP address:

`darknet.exe detector train data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show -mjpeg_port 8090 -map`

One should be able to open `http://ip-address:8090` in a Chrome/Firefox browser and see the chart. However, I am training my network on an AWS EC2 instance, and if I open the URL locally (on my laptop), I get the message 'ip address not found'.

Is is possible to view the chart? How can I get access to it while I am training remotely?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to view in a browser located on your remote instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So I need to open a browser on the EC2?

Comment: That is correct.